# Decoding emoji: it has a strange format I can't find elsewhere

Tags: php, emoji, decoding

This is the string I got:

`%uD83D%uDE0C`

I'm pretty sure it is an emoji, but when I try to decode it with this library: https://github.com/BriquzStudio/php-emoji, it does not work.

I also tried that library with php's `urldecode` function but with no luck.

Can somebody tell me what kind of decoding this is and/or how I can decode this?

Comment: a google of that string suggest utf-16 - http://www.charbase.com/1f60c-unicode-relieved-face

Comment: It looks like what's described as a "non-standard implementation" of percent-encoding here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the encoding appears to be non-standard, I recommend this:

```
$string = "%uD83D%uDE0C";
echo json_decode('"' . str_replace('%','\\',$string) . '"');
```

What it does is converts `"%uD83D%uDE0C"` to `"\uD83D\uDE0C"`, which is a valid javascript encoding. Then it uses json_decode to interpret the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It is Relieved Face.

You can find here more detail [in this link](http://www.charbase.com/1f60c-unicode-relieved-face).

- Java Escape :    "\ud83d\ude0c"
- Javascript Escape :  "\ud83d\ude0c"